# Remove HTTP:// or HTTPS:// from URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Simple question: Is it possible to remove `http://` or `https://` from the URL or at least hide it using mod_rewrite?

For instance, is it possible to make the URL `https://example.com` or `https://example.com/index.php` display as `example.com` or `example.com/index.php`?

Answer (score 0):

No. `http://` and `https://` are protocols among others like `ftp`, `sftp`, and `ssh`.

This is how the browser knows which port to connect by default if not specified in the URL. (http://portquiz.net:8080/)

For further reading see: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: so it's only possible with add-on domains since you're using `.htaccess` to simply redirect from, say, `public_html/addon/index.php` to `addondomain.com/index.php`?

Comment: also, can't you simply hide `https://` by redirecting `https://example.com/` to `example.com`, in which case the browser is still informed initially of which protocol is being used?

Comment: @Anthony no, that won't work. When the server sends a redirect, it needs to pass the absolute URL, including the `https://` part. That is why if you have a site with a link that doesn't have the protocol information, it will assume it's a relative URL. See: https://jsfiddle.net/dsxjznhw/

Comment: @Anthony may I ask why do you want it hidden?

Comment: `example.com` or `example.com/path/to/file` is just so much cleaner. less stuff in the address bar to distract you from being able to remember the url. i mean, modern browsers already tell you with the lock icon which protocol is being used right

Comment: Sure! But I never have to type or remember which protocol to use on which site. The browser remembers that. And if the server sends a HSTS header, the browser will remember to use `https` from that point forward.

Comment: yeah, but it would aid people's ability to visually memorize a URL if the URL wasn't clouded with `http(s)://`